# SwiftUI picker not changing selection with an Enum

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use an Enum with a SwiftUI picker, but can't get the picker to update the chosen value. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
enum WindowLayout: String, Equatable, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case oneByOne = "1 x 1"
    case oneByTwo = "1 x 2"
    case oneByThree = "1 x 3"
    case twoByOne = "2 x 1"
    case twoByTwo = "2 x 2"
    case twoByThree = "2 x 3"
    case threeByOne = "3 x 1"
    case threeByTwo = "3 x 2"
    
    var id: WindowLayout {
        self
    }
    
    var rows: Int {
        switch self {
        case .oneByOne, .oneByTwo, .oneByThree:
            return 1
        case .twoByOne, .twoByTwo, .twoByThree:
            return 2
        case .threeByOne, .threeByTwo:
            return 3
        }
    }
    
    var columns: Int {
        switch self {
        case .oneByOne, .twoByOne, .threeByOne:
            return 1
        case .oneByTwo, .twoByTwo, .threeByTwo :
            return 2
        case .oneByThree, .twoByThree :
            return 3
        }
    }
}


struct WindowCommands: Commands {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = GridConfigViewModel(windowLayout: WindowLayout.oneByOne)
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Video") {
            Picker(selection: $viewModel.windowLayout, label: Text("Window Configuration")) {
                ForEach(WindowLayout.allCases, id: \.id) {
                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GridConfigViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var windowLayout: WindowLayout {
        didSet {
            print("set \(windowLayout.rawValue)")
        }
    }
    
    init(windowLayout: WindowLayout) {
        self.windowLayout = windowLayout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the viewModel wrapped in a @Publisher in the caller of WindowCommand instead of inside WindowCommand. That caller should be an ObservableObject.

The @ObservedObject is the correct wrapper for the property in WindowCommand, but they way it is above means it's instantiated each time WindowCommand is called.

```
@Published var gridViewModel =  GridConfigViewModel(windowLayout: WindowLayout.oneByOne)
```

... then where WindowCommands is called ...

```
WindowCommand(viewModel: gridViewModel)
```